# Code in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code in Excel using VBA.
I have a huge table with lot of data in it, and I want to filter the table using few column headings.
In that I want to filter the column heading "Design Group". And I want only those numbers which start with "17" and has 5 digits "17###".

I tried using something like this:
(Left(Cells(x, 18), 2) = Format(17, "17###")
But, obviously this does not work!

It would be really helpful if someone can find a way around this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your cells contain numbers, you should really be using numeric tests such as

```
If Cells(x,18).Value >= 17000 And Cells(x,18).Value <= 17999 Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
IF (Left(Cells(x, 18), 2) = "17" and Len(Cells(x, 18))=5 Then
```

Comment: Won't that also pick up the number `173.2`?

Comment: @YowE3K yes it would.  Put your comment as an answer so I may delete mine.

Comment: I've posted an answer, but it might be best to leave yours as the OP said that worked.